# Visual Studio 2010 get information on property that is inherited

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, inheritance

When in the XAML designer, if I highlight a control (e.g. TextBox), and then I look at the TextBox in the Properties sheet, values that are inherited are shown, but when I hover over the inheritance symbol in the property sheet, the tooltip simply says "value source: Inheritance".

Is there a setting or an extension that can tell me where the value is inherited from?

Comment: It's really simpler to just look on MSDN for that. It can give you all the levels of depth you need to see where properties inherit from. Even when you start from the child element it will show all properties and indicate their parentage.

Comment: I don't quite understand.  How would looking on MSDN tell me about a particular property's inheritance?

Comment: Go to this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx. Now look for your property and follow the links to it's parent.

Comment: Ok, I understand where you're coming from.  My question is this:  I see that the FontFamily property of my particular textbox is "Arial", and that it is inherited.  This is all in my property sheet.  What I need to know is where in my code is this being inherited from?  If it would give me the file and line number it is coming from, that would be ideal.